# WPF C# datagrid combobox on new row won't update datasource (updated!)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, datagrid

This is an example exhibiting the behaviour I'm having trouble with. I have a datagrid which is bound to an observable collection of records in a viewmodel. In the datagrid I have a DataGridTemplateColumn holding a combobox which is populated from a list in the viewmodel. The datagrid also contains text columns. There are some textboxes at the bottom of the window to show the record contents.

```
<Window x:Class="Customer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Customer"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:SelectedRowConverter x:Key="selectedRowConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgCustomers" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding customers}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow,
                    Converter={StaticResource selectedRowConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  CanUserAddRows="True" Grid.Row="0" SelectionChanged="dgCustomers_SelectionChanged">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" Header="Country">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="cmbCountry" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.countries,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                      DisplayMemberPath="name" SelectedValuePath="name" Margin="5"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedCountry,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Mode=TwoWay,
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionChanged="cmbCountry_SelectionChanged" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding name}" Width="1*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone" Binding="{Binding phone}" Width="1*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <Grid x:Name="grdDisplay" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=dgCustomers}" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="Country:" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="4" Content="Code:" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            <BulletDecorator  Grid.Column="0">
                <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    <Label Content="Name:" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtId" Text="{Binding ElementName=dgCustomers, Path=SelectedItem.name}" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
            </BulletDecorator>
            <BulletDecorator Grid.Column="1">
                <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    <Label Content="Code:" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtCode" Text="{Binding ElementName=dgCustomers, Path=SelectedItem.countryCode}" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
            </BulletDecorator>
            <BulletDecorator Grid.Column="2">
                <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    <Label  Content="Phone:" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtPhone" Text="{Binding ElementName=dgCustomers, Path=SelectedItem.phone}" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
            </BulletDecorator>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Initially there are no records so the datagrid is empty and shows just one line containing the combobox. If the user enters data into the text columns first then a record is added to the collection and the combobox value can be added to the record. However, if the user selects the combobox value first, then the value disappears when another column is selected. How do I get the combobox data added to the record if it is selected first?

Codebehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public GridModel gridModel { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        gridModel = new GridModel();
        //dgCustomers.DataContext = gridModel;
        this.DataContext = gridModel;
    }

    private void cmbCountry_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox c = sender as ComboBox;
        Debug.Print("ComboBox selection changed, index is " + c.SelectedIndex + ", selected item is " + c.SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

The Record class:

```
public class Record : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _name;
    public string name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("name");
        }
    }

    private string _phone;
    public string phone
    {
        get { return _phone; }
        set
        {
            _phone = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("phone");
        }
    }

    private int _countryCode;
    public int countryCode
    {
        get { return _countryCode; }
        set
        {
            _countryCode = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("countryCode");
        }
    }
}
```

Country class:

```
public class Country : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _name;
    public string name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("name");
        }
    }

    private int _id;
    public int id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("id");
        }
    }

    private int _code;
    public int code
    {
        get { return _code; }
        set
        {
            _code = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("code");
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _name;
    }
}
```

GridModel:

```
public class GridModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Record> customers { get; set; }
    public List<Country> countries { get; set; }
    public GridModel()
    {
        customers = new ObservableCollection<Record>();
        countries = new List<Country> { new Country { id = 1, name = "England", code = 44 }, new Country { id = 2, name = "Germany", code = 49 },
        new Country { id = 3, name = "US", code = 1}, new Country { id = 4, name = "Canada", code = 11 }};
    }

    private Country _selectedCountry;
    public Country SelectedCountry
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedCountry;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedCountry = value;
            _selectedRow.countryCode = _selectedCountry.code;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRow");
        }
    }

    private Record _selectedRow;
    public Record SelectedRow
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedRow;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedRow = value;
            Debug.Print("Datagrid selection changed"); 
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRow");
        }
    }
}
```

Converters:

```
class Converters
{
}

public class SelectedRowConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Record)
            return value;
        return new Customer.Record();
    }
}
```

ViewModelBase:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModelBase()
    {

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you are seeing is as expected. The reason behind it is that the `ComboBox` `ItemsSource` as well as `SelectedItem` both are bound to `Properties` of the `Window`'s `DataContext` while the other columns are bound to your `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource`. Hence when you modify the columns other than the dropdown the data is added to the observable collection.

What you can do is after a value is selected from the drop down you need to add a record yourself (possibly by calling a function from your `SelectedCountry` property)

**EDIT**

Based on your code I made a working model making as little changes as possible to your existing code. I could not use the converter as I did not have the details of the class `Customer`

Xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Add User" Margin="0,2,2,2" Command="{Binding AddUserCommand}"/>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgCustomers"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding customers}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow}"
          SelectionUnit="FullRow"
          CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" Header="Country">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Focusable="False" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.countries, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                      DisplayMemberPath="name"
                                      SelectedValuePath="code"
                                      SelectedValue="{Binding countryCode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="1*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone" Binding="{Binding phone, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="1*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid x:Name="grdDisplay" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=dgCustomers}" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="Country:" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        <Label Grid.Column="4" Content="Code:" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        <BulletDecorator  Grid.Column="0">
            <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                <Label Content="Name:" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtId" Text="{Binding ElementName=dgCustomers, Path=SelectedItem.name}" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
        </BulletDecorator>
        <BulletDecorator Grid.Column="1">
            <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                <Label Content="Code:" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtCode" Text="{Binding ElementName=dgCustomers, Path=SelectedItem.countryCode}" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
        </BulletDecorator>
        <BulletDecorator Grid.Column="2">
            <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                <Label  Content="Phone:" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtPhone" Text="{Binding ElementName=dgCustomers, Path=SelectedItem.phone}" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
        </BulletDecorator>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Your GridModel class

```
public class GridModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Record> customers { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Country> countries
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public GridModel()
    {
        customers = new ObservableCollection<Record> { };
        AddUserCommand = new RelayCommand(AddNewUser);
        countries = new ObservableCollection<Country> 
        { 
            new Country { id = 1, name = "England", code = 44 },
            new Country { id = 2, name = "Germany", code = 49 },
            new Country { id = 3, name = "US", code = 1},
            new Country { id = 4, name = "Canada", code = 11 }
        };
    }

    private void AddNewUser()
    {
        customers.Add(new Record());
    }

    public ICommand AddUserCommand { get; set; }

    private Record _selectedRow;
    public Record SelectedRow
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedRow;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedRow = value;
            Debug.Print("Datagrid selection changed");
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRow");
        }
    }
}
```

I have used [MVVMLight](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight/) toolkit which contains `RelayCommand`. You can also define your own `ICommand` implementation and use it instead of the toolkit

**EDIT 2**

Fixed the bug introduced by me which would prevent the combobox from displaying the Country if the data comes from the data base. The improved code does not require any converter either

Comment: Hello Sandesh, thanks a lot for the answer! So when SelectedCountry is called I use the property to change the SelectedRow: `code`         set
            {
                _selectedCountry = value;
                _selectedRow.countryCode = _selectedCountry.code;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRow");
            } `code` I thought with two-way binding this would update the datagrid?

Comment: People would find it creepy if the datagrid displays a record which does not exist in its ItemsSource :)

Comment: Would save a lot of typing if it could just guess what you wanted though :) I have to explicitly add the SelectedRow to the ObservableCollection then, but only if it doesn't already exist... so I need to know which row the SelectedCountry is called from and only add it if the ObservableCollection doesn't contain that many rows. Any ideas on how I get the datagrid row index from inside the SelectedCountry property?

Comment: Generally DataGrid knows which Row is getting modified. If you provide details of your design I might be able to help

Comment: WPF is easy if you exactly know what you are doing

Comment: It seems you do :) Thanks for your time Sandesh!

Comment: The above solution I gave has a bug to be fixed.

Comment: Fixed the bug. Are you sure I just _seem_ to know what I am doing? just kidding :P